# Regex pattern matching not working recursivily

Tags: java, regex

I want to implement the pattern matching in the form

(a+b)(c-or*or/d)..............
in any number of times.

I use the following pattern but it is not working recursively.
It is just reading the first group.

```
Pattern pattern;
String regex="(([0-9]*)([+,-,/,*])([0-9]*)*)";
pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(userInput);
```

Comment: in which context are you using this. Can give a sample text to be tested with regex?

Comment: ok 15-9*12/5+9*4 i need to parse this as a user input and calculate this expression

Comment: calculate or check? regex is used for matching, checking not calculations.

Comment: i first need to check . For calculation i will use stack implementaton. I need to check if the input is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression you need to match that sort of sequence is this:

```
\s*-?\d+(?:\s*[-+/*]\s*-?\d+)+\s*
```

Let's break that down to it's component parts!

```regexp
\s*            # Optional space
-?             # Optional minus sign
\d+            # Mandatory digits
(?:            # Start sub-regex
   \s*         #    Optional space
   [-+*/]      #    Mandatory single arithmetic operator
   \s*         #    Optional space
   -?          #    Optional minus sign
   \d+         #    Mandatory digits
)+             # End sub-regex: want one or more matches of it
\s*            # Optional space
```

(If you don't want to match spaces, remove all of those `\s*` and be aware that it will surprise users quite a lot.)

Now, when encoding the above as a String literal in Java (before compilation) you need to be careful to escape each of the `\` characters in it:

```
String regex="\\s*-?\\d+(?:\\s*[-+/*]\\s*-?\\d+)+\\s*";
```

The other thing to be aware of is that this *doesn't* pull the regular expression apart into pieces for Java to parse and build an expression evaluation tree from; it just (with the rest of your code) matches the whole string or not. (Even putting in capturing parentheses wouldn't help a lot; when put inside some form of repetition, they only report the first place in the string where they matched.) The simplest way of doing that properly would be to use a parser generator like Antlr (it would also let you do things like parenthesized subexpressions, managing operator precedence, etc.)

Comment: Well thanks . Your regex just work fine for me. For parsing i m planning to use Stack implementation. thanks again.

Comment: @Rohit: "Stack implementation" is a lot like an LL parser, and that's what ANTLR is a tool for building. (With a name like that you'd think it would make LR parsers, but it doesn't; yet another missed opportunity for layers of cool names…)

Answer (score 0):

You will need an expression like this

```
[0-9]+-[0-9]+[\/*-+][0-9]+[\/*-+][0-9]+[\/*-+][0-9]+[\/*-+][0-9]+
```

You have to match the whole expression. You can not match part of the expression and do a second search because the pattern is repeated.

Note: In ruby \ is excape sequence of / character so you can omit it in C# or replace it with another characer.

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/YnF020sy4B)

Answer (score 0):

**The pattern**

```
<!--
\((\d|[\+\-\/\\\*\^%!]+|(or|and) *)+\)

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d|[\+\-\/\\\*\^%!]+|(or|and) *)+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «+»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\d»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[\+\-\/\\\*\^%!]+»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\+\-\/\\\*\^%!]+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
         A + character «\+»
         A - character «\-»
         A / character «\/»
         A \ character «\\»
         A * character «\*»
         A ^ character «\^»
         One of the characters “%!” «%!»
   Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(or|and) *»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(or|and)»
         Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «or»
            Match the characters “or” literally «or»
         Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «and»
            Match the characters “and” literally «and»
      Match the character “ ” literally « *»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “)” literally «\)»
-->
```

---

**The calculation algorithm**
For parsing and processing input string you have to use a stack. Visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29?) for the concept.

Regards
Cylian

Answer (score -1):

your expression doesnt escape special chars like +,(,)

try this

```
/\(\d+[\+|-|\/|\*]\d+)\G?/
```

\G is the whole pattern over again

? means the previous thing is optional

i changed your [0-9]* to \d+ which i think is more correct

i changed your , to |

Comment: Nah, `\G` doesn't work like your description. It matches boundary of last match - which means it asserts that position is where the last match ends.